# Operations on Numeral Types' lists According to Arguments

Tags: c++, parsing, operators

I have got a function which takes a list of operands (`float, int..etc`) and another list of an enum {`ADD, SUBTRACT, DIVIDE, MULTIPLY`} as arguments. What I want the function to do is take those and form an expression of it.

For instance, suppose I pass the operand `list<int> {2, 5, 6, 2}`, and the enum list {`MULTIPLY, ADD, DIVIDE`}. I would like the function to somehow generate and calculate an expression out of this `maintaining the order of operations`.

In this case, the expression would be `2*5+6/2` which would evaluate to `13`.

Doing

`Add(x,y) Subtract(x,y) Multiply(x,y) Divide(x,y)`

functions won't work because it will just end up breaking the order of operations at times. I don't want to code priority tables myself, and I know C++ operators do have priorities set already. Is there a way I can make use of that?

Comment: it may be a little "heavy weight" solution, but you can easily do this with an embedded script language. E.g `lua`. You could generate a string from the operands and the operators and simply pass that to the interpreter.

Comment: @Zoltán Hilóczki Yes, but that's the problem. My function will be run thousands of times per a frame, so I'm trying to have it perform as good as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I've done this is by using a `Tree data structure`. Multiplication and division operations, with both of their left and right operands, are put in deeper nodes of the tree. I then wrote an `Evaluate()` function which would go through the nodes down to top and evaluate every expression.

I assumed that would be faster than converting the expression to Reverse Polish Notation and then executing it when I need as suggested by Lorehead, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Shunting-Yard Algorithm to convert your infix expressions to a stack in Reverse Polish Notation, then execute the operations off the stack.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look it up.